# Sublime text : How to activate conda environment via build system

Tags: python, sublimetext3, anaconda, conda

I would like to configure a second build system for Python on Sublime text 3. By default it use Python 2.7. for the time being, if I want to use Python 3.5, I execute `activate py35` and it works like a charm.

Here is my original build system :

```
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "python", "-u", "-i", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_dir"
}
```

I added this line just before :

```
    "cmd": ["activate", "py35"],
```

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865717/use-conda-environment-in-sublime-text-3) but it didn't help, `which` command isn't recognized, even if my env is activated :

[image]

Comment: `which` is a Unix command. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line

Comment: IMO, a more elegant approach would be to add `python` to the PATH environmental variable. The Python installer for Windows has an option for that, but it's unchecked by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add another `"cmd"`. JSON doesn't allow duplicate keys.

You also don't need to activate anything. Give the full path to the Python executable

For example

```
"cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "C:/Users/name/path/py35/Scripts/python",
```