# How to automatically set conda virtual environment of `python_interpreter` in Sublime Text Anaconda package?

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3

- OS: Bigsur 11.3.1
- Sublime text: 3.2.2
- Sublime text extension(package): [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/)
- Python virtual environment management using `Miniconda`(`Anaconda`)
- Use [autoenv](https://github.com/inishchith/autoenv) per each workspace directory

When I open the workspace folder and work on it in Sublime text, I usually go to the directory via Terminal(using `cd`) and use `subl .` to open it. (If I moved to the directory, its virtual environment would be activated cuz I used `autoenv` mentioned above)

And In the package settings(User's custom setting) of [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/), I can set `python_interpreter`, so whenever I use a function like `Go to definition` of the `Class` of 3rd party library, it reflects its installed libraries and get me there. The setting looks like this: `"python_interpreter": "/Users/chois/miniconda3/envs/MY_VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME/bin/python"`

But the problem is, it is set with `"python_interpreter": "/Users/chois/miniconda3/bin/python"` as a default, which is a `(base)` interpreter, not a virtual environment of the directory. So whenever I worked on that workspace, I had to manually change it.

What I tried is something like `"python_interpreter": "/Users/chois/miniconda3/envs/$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python",` but the sublime text doesn't recognize the environment variable in the package setting.

How can I flexibly set `python_interpreter` as each working directory's virtual environment's interpreter path, say, `"/Users/chois/miniconda3/envs/$CURRENT_DIRS_VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME/bin/python"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use conda environment in sublime text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865717/use-conda-environment-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: @Roim Hmm.. all solutions are not working...

Comment: Can't understand why my question is closed automatically.  Mine is a different question from the one Roim mentioned..

Comment: @user3595632 You are correct. I've reopened it for you. I'd recommend doing some research on reading external environment variables within Sublime. You may be able to write a plugin to do your task for you.