# Sublime text conda package doesn't find environments

Tags: conda, sublimetext3, sublimetext, miniconda

I installed the sublime-text-conda package through the package control manager on Sublime text built 4152, on Windows 11. I already have Miniconda installed in the system with an environment that works well. I tried to configure the conda settings so that it would use my miniconda installation (following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865717/use-conda-environment-in-sublime-text-3)), my settings look like this now:

```
{
    "executable": "C:\\Users\\xxx\\miniconda3\\python.exe",
    "environments_directory": "C:\\Users\\xxx\\miniconda3\\envs\\",
    "run_through_shell": true
}
```

However if I try to run any related command in the command palette, ex. conda: activate environment, or conda: list environment. it only finds the base env. Which is annoying, because I would like to use the environments already created (I have only one now and it runs python 3.11).
Then I tried to create a new environment form the command palette, because I wanted to see if it could be detected in this case. It seemed to be created ok, in fact I can see it from my powershell if I list the environments, however conda  in Sublime still fails to find it (I tried to restart ST a few times in all of that but didn't make much of a difference).

Note that I know how to create a new build to a conda env (as per the first answer in the linked SO thread), but I thought it would be a bit more convenient having the possibility to use the environments directly from ST, instead of having to create a build every time I have to make a new environment.

So any help/suggestion is appreciated